# DB - Is table with just one column the right way?

Tags: database

i am trying to build a db structure for a multi-language admin panel, and one of the entities is Meal_Plans which will also be referenced by other tables in the design. I can't see at the moment useful attributes that will not have to be translated rather than **id** (even **"active"** won't be needed because all of the Meal Plans will be active by default), so the right way of doing things should be

```
TABLE Meal_PLans
id

TABLE MealPlan_Translations
mealplan_id
language_code
name
description
PRIMARY_KEY (mealplan_id, language_code)
```

Is having a table with just one column legit? Because referencing **mealplan_id** inside **MealPlan_Translations** won't be correct, given that it won't be a unique value in that table.

Thanks for your help

Comment: So what would happen to your data model if the PK of your table was just `mealplan_id`? would everything still work? Just a thought experiment to try and flush out the true meaning of `mealplan_id`

Comment: If you are talking about the second table, MealPlan_Translations, it can't be the only primary key because there would be more than one row with the same value for that column (1, 'it', '...', '...'), (1, 'en', '...', '...') etc....

Comment: 1,it 2,en  If the id has no meaning then it doesn’t matter. That’s the thought experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a structure makes sense. It captures the concept of a `MealPlan` being an entity; you also keep the door open for possible future additions to the model.

Other option would be to only use a sequence for generating `MealPlan` id's and only capture them in the `MealPlan_Translations` table. Specifics depend on the DB you're using, e.g. [MSSQL docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15).
This option is also viable, but it doesn't allow a situation where a MealPlan doesn't have a translation (which may or may not be OK, depending on the domain you're modelling).

Comment: If I'd use Sequences and not an actual table, i would still have troubles with the foreign key constraint when i will have to reference a specifil MealPlan from other tables (where i will only need the MealPlan id and not the translation). Thanks for the advise anyway

Comment: @Sergio agreed, if you want to use the id as a foreign key elsewhere, it's definitely the way to go.